# Inverting y-axis with customized ticks

Tags: plotting, style, ticks, scaling

Consider the following tick-styling function

```
tickFunc = MapAt[Reverse, {All, 3}]@*Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.01, .005}];
```

which leads to

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 10],
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}}]
```

[image]

Now, I want to invert the y-axis, which would supposedly be done with `ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}`, but

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 10],
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}},
    ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}]
```

yields an error with the message "TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]". How can I solve this?

Interestingly enough, with `Plot` this issue doesn't occur

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10},
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}},
    ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

Any ideas?

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"
> ```

Comment: I don't get any errors on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed I am using v13.3.0, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, but using `tickFunc[##]&` instead of `tickFunc` in setting `FrameTicks` eliminates the issue:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 10], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc[##] &, None}, {tickFunc[##] &, None}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define the tick function as

```
tickFunc2 = MapAt[Reverse, {All, 3}]@
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
      "TicksLength" -> {.01, .005}][##] &;

ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 10], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc2, None}, {tickFunc2, None}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"
> ```

Comment: Interesting! I am also not sure why that happens. Thanks.